# InflateException with custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-inflate

I use a custom view (very similar to the `NetworkImageView` from Volley) in my application.
When I inflate it on an adapter (ex: in a listview) **it works perfectly**.

**But** I receive a weird `InflateException` when I try to use it directly into a `Fragment` :
Its weird because the ClassName appears different in the stack

The Exception :

```
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class NetworkImageViewTransformed
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at com.myapp.fragments.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:81)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.NetworkImageViewTransformed" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.myapp-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater
```

And here's my XML (part of):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.myapp.views.TransformedNetworkImageView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/blur_picture"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    />
 </FrameLayout>
```

As you can see my View should be an instance of `com.myapp.views.TransformedNetworkImageView` but the stack reffers to `NetworkImageViewTransformed` and `android.view.NetworkImageViewTransformed`

I already tried to Invalidate the cache; clean ; rebuild ; restart Android studio... Nothing changes.

Edit the `onCreateView` (Crashes on the inflation):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);


    mBlurPicture = (TransformedNetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.blur_picture);
    .....
    return view;
}
```

And here the full code of `TransformedNetworkImageView` :

```
public class TransformedNetworkImageView extends ImageView {
/**
 * Interface to transform the bitmap image before the draw
 */
public static interface OnBitmapDisplayedListener {
    public Bitmap onBitmapDisplayed(Bitmap downloadedBitmap);
}

/** The URL of the network image to load */
private String mUrl;

/**
 * Resource ID of the image to be used as a placeholder until the network image is loaded.
 */
private int mDefaultImageId;

/**
 * Resource ID of the image to be used if the network response fails.
 */
private int mErrorImageId;

/** Local copy of the ImageLoader. */
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

/** Current ImageContainer. (either in-flight or finished) */
private ImageContainer mImageContainer;


private OnBitmapDisplayedListener mBitmapDisplayedListener;

public TransformedNetworkImageView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
    init();
}

public TransformedNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    init();
}

public TransformedNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}


/**
 * Sets URL of the image that should be loaded into this view. Note that calling this will
 * immediately either set the cached image (if available) or the default image specified by
 * {@link TransformedNetworkImageView#setDefaultImageResId(int)} on the view.
 *
 * NOTE: If applicable, {@link TransformedNetworkImageView#setDefaultImageResId(int)} and
 * {@link TransformedNetworkImageView#setErrorImageResId(int)} should be called prior to calling
 * this function.
 *
 * @param url The URL that should be loaded into this ImageView.
 * @param imageLoader ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
 */
public void setImageUrl(String url, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
    mUrl = url;
    mImageLoader = imageLoader;
    // The URL has potentially changed. See if we need to load it.
    loadImageIfNecessary(false);
}

/**
 * Sets the default image resource ID to be used for this view until the attempt to load it
 * completes.
 */
public void setDefaultImageResId(int defaultImage) {
    mDefaultImageId = defaultImage;
}

/**
 * Sets the error image resource ID to be used for this view in the event that the image
 * requested fails to load.
 */
public void setErrorImageResId(int errorImage) {
    mErrorImageId = errorImage;
}

/**
 * Loads the image for the view if it isn't already loaded.
 * @param isInLayoutPass True if this was invoked from a layout pass, false otherwise.
 */
void loadImageIfNecessary(final boolean isInLayoutPass) {
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    boolean wrapWidth = false, wrapHeight = false;
    if (getLayoutParams() != null) {
        wrapWidth = getLayoutParams().width == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        wrapHeight = getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    }

    // if the view's bounds aren't known yet, and this is not a wrap-content/wrap-content
    // view, hold off on loading the image.
    boolean isFullyWrapContent = wrapWidth && wrapHeight;
    if (width == 0 && height == 0 && !isFullyWrapContent) {
        return;
    }

    // if the URL to be loaded in this view is empty, cancel any old requests and clear the
    // currently loaded image.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mUrl)) {
        if (mImageContainer != null) {
            mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
            mImageContainer = null;
        }
        setDefaultImageOrNull();
        return;
    }

    // if there was an old request in this view, check if it needs to be canceled.
    if (mImageContainer != null && mImageContainer.getRequestUrl() != null) {
        if (mImageContainer.getRequestUrl().equals(mUrl)) {
            // if the request is from the same URL, return.
            return;
        } else {
            // if there is a pre-existing request, cancel it if it's fetching a different URL.
            mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
            setDefaultImageOrNull();
        }
    }

    // Calculate the max image width / height to use while ignoring WRAP_CONTENT dimens.
    int maxWidth = wrapWidth ? 0 : width;
    int maxHeight = wrapHeight ? 0 : height;

    // The pre-existing content of this view didn't match the current URL. Load the new image
    // from the network.
    ImageContainer newContainer = mImageLoader.get(mUrl,
            new ImageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (mErrorImageId != 0) {
                        setImageBitmap(mBitmapDisplayedListener.onBitmapDisplayed(
                                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),
                                        mErrorImageId)));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(final ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                    // If this was an immediate response that was delivered inside of a layout
                    // pass do not set the image immediately as it will trigger a requestLayout
                    // inside of a layout. Instead, defer setting the image by posting back to
                    // the main thread.
                    if (isImmediate && isInLayoutPass) {
                        post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                onResponse(response, false);
                            }
                        });
                        return;
                    }

                    if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                        setImageBitmap(mBitmapDisplayedListener.onBitmapDisplayed(
                                                                response.getBitmap()));
                    } else if (mDefaultImageId != 0) {
                        setImageBitmap(mBitmapDisplayedListener.onBitmapDisplayed(
                            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),
                                    mDefaultImageId)));
                    }
                }
            }, maxWidth, maxHeight);

    // update the ImageContainer to be the new bitmap container.
    mImageContainer = newContainer;
}


/**
 * Initiate the default bitmap transformation listener
 */
private void init() {
    setOnBitmapDisplayedListener(new OnBitmapDisplayedListener() {
        @Override
        public Bitmap onBitmapDisplayed(final Bitmap downloadedBitmap) {
            return downloadedBitmap;
        }
    });
}

public void setOnBitmapDisplayedListener(OnBitmapDisplayedListener listener) {
    mBitmapDisplayedListener = listener;
}

private void setDefaultImageOrNull() {
    if(mDefaultImageId != 0) {
        setImageBitmap(mBitmapDisplayedListener.onBitmapDisplayed(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),
                        mDefaultImageId)));        }
    else {
        setImageBitmap(null);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    loadImageIfNecessary(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    if (mImageContainer != null) {
        // If the view was bound to an image request, cancel it and clear
        // out the image from the view.
        mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
        setImageBitmap(null);
        // also clear out the container so we can reload the image if necessary.
        mImageContainer = null;
    }
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
}

@Override
protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    invalidate();
}
}
```

Comment: can you post onCreateView from ProfileFragment?

Comment: Could you post your TransformedNetworkImageView class?

Comment: I edited with the code, but as I said, the view works in an adpater...

Answer (score 2):

That was definitely a cache issue, thanks Android Studio...

FYI: I closed my project, closed the IDE, launched `./gradlew clean` and reboot to get it working.